# V 9 FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

*can't add new document to firestore*
I am new to vue and firestore.
This is my config file.
[[image: this is my DataServices directory>>C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\src\Services\DataServices.js][1]][image: This is vue directory>>C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\covidcare-ytu-clinic\src\views\ClientForm.vue]

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth"
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 
  projectId: "covidcare-ytu-clinic",
  
}

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore()

connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8081)

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099")

export default { db, auth }
```

This is my Dataservice.js

```
import { db } from "@/firebase"
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore"
class dataService {
  /* async getAll() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "clients"))
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=> ", doc.data())
    })
  }*/
  async create(data) {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cli"), data)
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e)
    }
  }
  /*
  update(id, data) {
    return db.collection("clients").doc(id).updateDoc(data)
  }
  delete(id) {
    return db.collection("clients").doc(id).delete()
  }*/version-8 firebase
}
export default new dataService()
```

Here is my firebase error ..I couldn't add any document to my firestore.This is stacking me so long .

```
DataServices.js:15 Error adding document:  FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(db)` right before `addDoc()`  statement and share a screenshot of output ? I would try importing using relative path instead of `@/firebase` once.

Comment: yes sir@Dharmaraj i already console.log(db) before addDoc() .

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what it logs ?

Comment: in console. >> undefined appear.

Comment: Then it's wrong path.. can you share a screenshot of your directory structure ?

Comment: sorry for inconvenient i dun know how to comment photo

Comment: You can upload it somewhere n share link or click  `Ctrl + G` while editing question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer .When somebody face this kind of  problems like me , i hope this helpful .
i delete **default** in config file where i should write **export { db ,auth}** .

Answer (score 0):

In `Dataservice.js`, try using relative path for importing db:

```
// Remove this
// import { db } from "@/firebase"

// Try this
import { db } from "../../firebase" // relative path to config file
```

Comment: still getting the same error sir

Comment: @Bubblegum can you share your directory structure ?

Comment: Yes @Dharmaraj I re-edit my question sir

Comment: @Bubblegum in dataservice, did you change import path to `import { db } from "../firebase"`? or `../../firebase` as in my answer

Comment: import { db } from "../firebase"  in Dataservice.js sir

Comment: @Bubblegum it should work ideally then, what does `db` log now before addDoc ?

Comment: console.log(db);>> undefined sir